# search against a string + string with numeric suffix and fetch corresponding data

Tags: r

[image]

I have data frame as shown here

I have extracted `9350` from Material

I have extracted corresponding MRP area that pertains to `9350` in data frame B
Now I need to check, whether each entry (string) with `9350` + `BIN` 1 to N has all the requisite MRP area assigned against them

For example: `DT-9350-BIN7-C-B1` should have 
(The following available in data frame B)

```
8000_AMKR
8000_ATTW
8000_PWOO
```

same way to check for `DT-9350-BIN7-C-B1` and so on
That is BIN no incrementing

Please guide / help me

Comment: Please avoid posting pictures of data. Provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the forum and read up on the help centre to find out how to ask a question. We are here to help troubleshoot your code. Please update your question with what you have done and someone can have a look at it.